# Convergence of certain sequence in a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $(A,\mathbb{R},\alpha)$ be a $C^*$-dynamical system. Consider the following sequence of elements in $A$ defined by

$x_n=\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\alpha_t(x)e^{-nt^2}dt$.

How to prove that $x_n \rightarrow x$ in norm?

Comment: Where did this question come from?  Why do you expect $x_n$ to converge to $x$?

Comment: I want to prove that $\alpha$- analytic elements are norm dense in $A$. I could prove that each $x_n$ is $\alpha$. I want to prove the convergence.

Comment: Maybe there's a more clever way to go about this than what I'm doing, but in order to get the bounds to work out nicely, we need some strong decay condition on $\|\alpha_t(x)-x\|$ as $t\to 0$.